# About brackets and html, error says i have not index file but there is

Tags: html, css

What is wrong with this code? it works in code academy. I am really new to html, therefore I am still testing the waters with this. I just downloaded brackets to start doing my own thing outside code academy, but this is seriously holding me down. What seems to be wrong with this?
Brackets throws an error everytime I try to live preview. It says: "make sure there is an html file or that i have an index.html file in the folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>
        <title>Free Play!</title>
        <h1>
            <strong>
                    <em>And then there was her...</em>
            </strong> 
        </h1>
    </head>
    <body>>
    <div align = center>
    <img src= "http://cdn.sheknows.com/articles/2011/09/couple-arguing-in-kitchen.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div align = "center">
          <table>
          <thead>
          <th colspan = "2;">Dialog betwen two idiots<th>
          <thead>
                 <tr>
                      <td style="font-size: 18px"><strong>Me:</strong></td>
                      <td><strong>Her:<strong></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                      <td><em>Hey!</em></td>
                      <td><em>-yeah?</em></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                      <td><em>do you care?</em></td>
                      <td><em>-don't think so!</em></td>
                 </tr>
          </table>
       </div>
          <p><em><strong>
          "Life is too short to be wasting time being stupid, enjoy what you have and live!"

           </strong></em></p>

    </body>
</html>
```

This is the css part of the code.

```
body{
    background-image = url("http://www.rabne.tk/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/1dcb945e76e166670e8ab59fd7378901.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
     background-color: #cccccc;
    }
h1{
    text-align: center;
    color: solid black;
    background-color: orange;
    }
th{
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 30px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid black;
    }
td{
    text-align: left;
    background-color: orange;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    border-left:  2px solid black;
    border-top: 2px solid black;

    }

img{
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
    border-right: 5px solid black;
    border-left:  2px solid black;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    }
table{
    text-align: right;
     }

p{
    text-align: center;
    }
```

Comment: At least there are two ">" after the first body tag.

Comment: Anyway, what's in your project folder?

Comment: i have that html and a css file, tbh i dont even know how to set up a project in brackets, there is only an option do create a "new", but there isnt a project option...

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax errors all over the place, try this out:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>
        <title>Free Play!</title>

    </head>
    <body>
            <h1>
            <strong>
                    <em>And then there was her...</em>
            </strong> 
        </h1>
                <div align = "center">
                        <img src= "http://cdn.sheknows.com/articles/2011/09/couple-arguing-in-kitchen.jpg"/>
                </div>
                <div align = "center">
                      <table>
                          <thead>
                              <th colspan = "2">Dialog betwen two idiots<th>
                          <thead>
                             <tr>
                                  <td style="font-size: 18px"><strong>Me:</strong></td>
                                 <td><strong>Her:</strong></td>
                             </tr>
                             <tr>
                                  <td><em>Hey!</em></td>
                                  <td><em>-yeah?</em></td>
                             </tr>
                             <tr>
                                  <td><em>do you care?</em></td>
                                  <td><em>-don't think so!</em></td>
                             </tr>
                      </table>
               </div>
          <p><em><strong>
          "Life is too short to be wasting time being stupid, enjoy what you have and live!"

           </strong></em></p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Also change

```
background-image = `url("http://www.rabne.tk/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/1dcb945e76e166670e8ab59fd7378901.jpg");`
```

to

```
`background-image: url("http://www.rabne.tk/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/1dcb945e76e166670e8ab59fd7378901.jpg");`
```

Comment: Are you using this locally?

Comment: Ok just closed brackets, and went to the folder, opened the index.html and it loads the page as it should be. However after loading with brackets the error persists.

Comment: Yeah, it's  a local project, I have used dreamweaver before, it was so much easier than this. Brackets is akward to use.

Comment: It works out of brackets, but it doesnt work in brackets, it never compiles a preview.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone, this problem can be resolved by following steps:-

1. On menu bar, go to  File --> Open Folder (folder which have your html file for live preview)
2. Select Folder
3. Select your html file from left side bar for live preview
4. Click on bolt icon on right (preview button)

All it melts down to the fact, that you need that folder(which have your file) selected to view your output in live preview. 
Let me know, if it helps someone. :)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]